# 3.0.2 Devise recover password. Unauthorized. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords, customization

I'm having a problem with recovering a new password.  I've got the mailer setup and I'm receiving the password instructions fine.  When I click the reset password link in my email, I get to the change to new password page fine.  However, when I input a new password, I get a "Please review the following problems" with no errors and the password has not been changed.

When I check the logs I see this:

```
2013-10-08T17:10:35.118663+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/users/password" for 24.87.52.189 at 2013-10-08 17:10:35 +0000
2013-10-08T17:10:35.354246+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#update as HTML
2013-10-08T17:10:35.354246+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7LQ4VtOfwDZTV2tw4YwPoj8sqD6UGeCd5NvQkdANrH0=", "user"=>{"reset_password_token"=>"    [FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change my password"}
2013-10-08T17:10:35.354246+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.4ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.354246+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/passwords/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (5.2ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.354246+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.354246+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.354246+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 232ms (Views: 8.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.741022+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/password host=skalefree.net fwd="24.87.52.189" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=302 bytes=101
2013-10-08T17:10:35.725344+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/password" for 24.87.52.189 at 2013-10-08 17:10:35 +0000
2013-10-08T17:10:35.883843+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.6ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.883843+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.883843+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.3ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.883843+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.883843+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 19.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.354246+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.735631+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"password"}
2013-10-08T17:10:35.883843+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
**2013-10-08T17:10:35.735631+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms**
2013-10-08T17:10:35.735631+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#show as */*
2013-10-08T17:10:35.883843+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.5ms)
2013-10-08T17:10:35.856371+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 24.87.52.189 at 2013-10-08    17:10:35 +0000
2013-10-08T17:09:38.753083+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_in host=www.skalefree.net fwd="24.87.52.189" dyno=web.1 connect=14ms service=45ms status=200 bytes=3688
2013-10-08T17:10:35.892408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_in host=skalefree.net fwd="24.87.52.189" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=40ms status=200 bytes=3783
```

As you can see, I have a 301 unauthorized there.  Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Here are my routes:

```
devise_for :users, skip: :registrations

devise_scope :user do

  resource :registration,

  only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update],

  path: 'users',

  path_names: { new: 'sign_up' },

  controller: 'devise/registrations',

  as: :user_registration do

    get :cancel

  end

end
```

And my user model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

And my initializer:

```
config.reset_password_keys = [ :email ]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: consider upgrading devise to a newer version and see if it still doesn't work. `3.1.x`

Comment: Hello,

Devise 3.1 brought about new security changes that seems to make implementation more complicated. I was initially on 3.1 and I downgraded hoping that was the solution. lol

Answer (score 0):

The unauthorized looks like its coming from:

```
Started GET "/users/password" for 24.87.52.189 at 2013-10-08 17:10:35 +0000
...
   Parameters: {"id"=>"password"}
```

And there is no user with :id password, or something like that. Which basically means it's not redirecting correctly, or you're overriding something. The timeline should be the following:

Enter email address and click send instructions button:

```
Started POST "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-08 14:22:02 -0400
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
```

Click link in email message to reset password:

```
Started GET "/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=[FILTERED]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-08 14:22:19 -0400
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
```

Submit form with password and confirmation:

```
Started PUT "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-08 14:22:24 -0400
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#update as HTML
...
Redirected to <some-url-here>
Completed 302 Found in 243ms (ActiveRecord: 6.9ms)
```

It looks like your update method in the passwords controller is not redirecting. See if setting the `after_sign_in_path_for` method in your application controller to a path that is not a devise path fixes it:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  some_path
end
```

Comment: Do I need a before filter to make that method work?  And what variable should I use for (user)?  Current_user?

Comment: you just define it in application controller. `user` is the devise resource that just got signed in (so current_user) to my understanding

Comment: The problem still persists and the logs look the same.  Why does it start a get request to "/users/password" and why is that being processed by "UsersController#show".  This leads to the unauthorized error. If it sends a get request to users/password, shouldn't it be processed by the password controller in devise?

Comment: no, there is no get /users/password path with devise. For some reason it is redirecting there! Can't tell you why. You can a new route for it as a sort of patch for the time being to point to another url

Comment: You mean like this in my routes.rb?

    devise_scope :user do
    get "password", :to => 'findposts#findyou'
    end

Comment: yea as a hack for now

Comment: Well, that solved the unauthorized part.  It no longer shows up in the logs, but I still don't get signed in.  I think for some reason the "update" action isn't signing the user in. I think I'm getting some sort of error at this part of the update action:

self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)